# How to run a Powershell DSC script locally

Tags: web-services, powershell, dsc

I'm trying to run a very simple Powershell DSC script locally. (I never plan on pulling or pushing configuration files at this stage)

I get the following error message. The WS-Management service is running, but there are no firewall holes or ports reserved (server happens to be a webserver)... Is there anyway I can allow this server is only accept local requests?

> The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.
>   Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
>   requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
>   service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
>   destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
>   destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
>   quickconfig".
>       + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338012
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

```
 configuration SampleIISInstall
    {
        Node 127.0.0.1
        {
          File FileDemo {
            Type = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\TestUser3'
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        }
    }

    # Compile the configuration file to a MOF format
    SampleIISInstall

    # Run the configuration on localhost
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\SampleIISInstall -Wait -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
configuration SampleIISInstall
    {
        Node "localhost"
        {
          File FileDemo {
            Type = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\TestUser3'
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        }
    }

    # Compile the configuration file to a MOF format
    SampleIISInstall

    # Run the configuration on localhost
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\SampleIISInstall -Wait -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

Since DSC Uses PowerShell remoting you can't use IP addresses for the nodename you have to specify a computer name. Using localhost or $env:computername should work you could also remove the node block completely and just write the DSC config without it.

```
 configuration SampleIISInstall
    {
          File FileDemo {
            Type = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\TestUser3'
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        }

    # Compile the configuration file to a MOF format
    SampleIISInstall

    # Run the configuration on localhost
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\SampleIISInstall -Wait -Force -Verbose
```